# spring mvc ajax get work but post not work when i send request to remote server from localhost

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

```
  $(".submit").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      async: true,
      crossDomain: true,
      method: "post",
      data: $("form[name=something]").serialize(),
      url: "myUrl",
      success: function (res) {
        console.log(res);
      },
      error: function (res) {
        console.log(res.status);
      },
    });
  });
```

and my spring mvc controller like

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = {"*"},
        methods = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST,
            RequestMethod.PUT, RequestMethod.DELETE})
public class AppController {
...
...
...
}
```

> If is send (get) request it work properly but when i send (post) it got exception :
> Access to XMLHttpRequest at (remote server)from origin (localhost)has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the CORS policy is opened at the remote domain. if not, you will get the same error.
Also if you are using Spring and created/extended a WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter file, you can configure the CORS by redefining CorsConfigurationSource bean in the WebSecurityConfig file. just make sure to add your localhost url in allowed origins.

Something like below:

```
@Bean
  public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(ImmutableList.of("..your localhost url.."));
    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
  }
```